# State with Megaparsec ParsecT is not backtracking

Tags: haskell, state, monads, monad-transformers, megaparsec

I have a parser defined as a slightly more complicated version of the following:

```
data X = X { getX :: State ([Int], [X]) Bool }
type Parser = ParsecT Void String (State ([Int], [X]))
```

The idea is that I can build up a stack of actions I want to do to my state (the `[Int]`) and then execute them in any order or whenever I want, depending on the circumstances:

```
-- Run the first state in the list.
executeOne :: Parser Bool
executeOne = do
  s@(_, fs) <- get
  let (r, s') = (flip runState s) . getX . head $ fs
  put s'
  return r
```

For example, the action executed may reorder the stack of actions or modify the `[Int]`.

Design decisions aside (I'm sure there are better ways to do this), it seems that backtracking with `try` is not working with the state. Specifically, the state of the ParsecT will backtrack, but the inner state (the `[Int]` and `[X]`) won't. Why is this? Am I misusing ParsecT or is the strange recursive `X` business screwing everything over? Do I need to use `Control.Monad.State.Strict` instead?

Edit: To answer a commenter's question about an example `X`, here's one:

```
useless :: X
useless = X $ do
  (vs, xs) <- get
  if length vs >= 10
  then do { put (vs, tail xs) ; return True }
  else do { put (vs ++ vs, xs) ; return False }
```

`useless` doubles our `[Int]` if it has less than ten elements, and returns `False`. If it does have ten or more elements, it removes itself and returns `True`. The power in having `X` be recursive is that it can choose whether or not to remove itself after it's done.

Comment: It has to do with the ordering of the monad stack. A monad transformer can't "undo" an effect performed by monads below it. You could try putting a `StateT` transformer above the `Parser` monad. You won't have to perform any lifts because there is a `MonadParsec e s m => MonadParsec e s (StateT st m)` instance.

Comment: Tangential question: why have you defined an infinitely recursive state type? If you expand the newtypes, you get that `X` is `State ([Int], [State ([Int], [State ([Int], ...)])])`. What purpose does this type serve?

Comment: @danidiaz Why is that? That seems interesting.

Comment: @bradrn I don't know the ultimate reason, but it seems to be the rule. For example, `StateT` over `ExceptT` loses its state on failure, while `ExceptT` over `StateT` doesn't. `ListT` over `StateT` has its state shared across all search branches, while `StateT` over `ListT` has a different state for each branch.

Comment: @danidiaz I think that's because monad transformers work 'inside out', so e.g. an `ExceptT a (ExceptT b Identity) x` is equivalent to an `Either b (Either a x)`. I've always wondered why that is, although my question https://stackoverflow.com/q/49587122/7345298 may help.

Comment: Related question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/27835214/637669

Comment: @bradrn Think of `X` like an action that can be performed on my state. I can make a  list of actions, then run the top one with `executeOne`. The thing is, I want an `X` to have control over the `[X]` inside the parser state - for example, a specific `X` might not remove itself from the list until the `[Int]` is a specific length, or it might throw away some actions below it in the list if the head of `[Int]`  is negative (just random examples). It provides the most freedom as they have 100% full control over the state.

Comment: @otah007 It's starting to make sense to me, but I still don't entirely understand. Could you give me a small example of a value of type `X`?

Comment: @danidiaz, this is indeed a very interesting question in general. I strongly suspect the a answer will relate to the general nature of functions used to "run" computations in transformed monads. But I don't know how to formalize the question, let alone answer it!

Comment: @bradrn I've added an example to the question.

Comment: @danidiaz I think I've been misunderstanding the instances of `MonadParsec` - I knew `StateT` was an instance but I had it backward. Just to make sure, `MonadParsec e s m` guarantees backtracking via `try` for `StateT st m`, and in this case we want `m = ParsecT...`. But because `ParsecT` is not an instance of `MonadParsec`, the monad `ParsecT e s (StateT...` won't backtrack the inner `m`, that is, the inner `StateT...`. Is that correct?

Comment: @otah007 That example makes sense. Personally I would have defined `newtype X = X { getX :: ([Int], [X]) -> ([Int], [X], Bool) }`, so getting rid of the confusing recursive `State` definition, but it doesn't really make much difference. Also as for your previous comment I'm pretty sure that `ParsecT` is an instance of `MonadParsec`.

Comment: @otah007 `ParsecT` is an instance of `MonadParsec`. `MonadParsec` is a convenience, it helps you avoid having to sprinkle your code with `lift`s when there's a transformer above `ParsecT`. It doesn't care about transformers below `ParsecT`. `StateT` above `ParsecT` happens to have the backtracking behaviour you need, and also happens to have a `MonadParsec` instance.

Comment: @danidiaz If you add that as an answer then I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was the order of the transformers in the monad stack.

Informally speaking, a transformer can't "cancel" or "nullify" the effects of the base monad it transforms. For example, `StateT` over `ExceptT` loses its state on failure, while `ExceptT` over `StateT` doesn't. (This is also the reason why there can't be an `IOT` transformer: how to nullify a effect that has already escaped into the world?)

Here, it means that the inner `State` will survive any backtracking of the parser. The solution is to put `StateT` *above* the parser monad, not below.

This would seem to require `lift` calls for all the parser functions, because the parser is not the outermost monad now. Fortunately, the `lift`s aren't needed because `StateT s Parser` is an instance of [`MonadParsec`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/megaparsec-7.0.4/docs/Text-Megaparsec.html#t:MonadParsec), which auto-lifts all parser operations.